# pygame - collision detection and solid object creation

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, game-physics

So this question is following up on my question from yesterday regarding pygame collision detection and solid object creation. Here's my new code:

```
if player.rect.left >= rect.right + 1:
        player.undo_right()
    if player.rect.right <= rect.left - 1:
        player.undo_left()
    if player.rect.bottom <= rect.top + 2:
        player.undo_top()
    if player.rect.top >= rect.bottom + 2:
        player.undo_bottom()
```

At the moment, this handles some basic collision detection. If the player's x-value/y-value is greater/less than the target surface, the player is moved a certain amount. The problem is that this just makes the player all "jittery" and the player is still able to pass through my object.

So I guess my question at this point is how can I make so the player can't pass through an object? I've tried player.rect.colliderect but get much the same result as above.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this effectively which is why I'm turning to you guys. I could bang my head against a wall for a few hours, but I'd rather get critique and advice from the community first.

Anyway, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think problem can be in all code, not only in this part so nobody can answer for your question.

Comment: at this moment I can only suggest that you analyze code in
[Platformer examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38) (at the end of page)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrectly detecting collisions because it doesn't check that multiple conditions are true at the same time. Currently, any time the player is to the right of an object, he counts as colliding with its left side. Similarly, if he's above it, he counts as hitting its bottom. (Or something like that, I'm not sure I grasp how your axes are aligned, given your current code.)

It's a lot easier to tell when objects *don't* collide than it is to tell how they collide if they do. If one object's right side is to the left of the other object's left side, they obviously can't be touching at all. Similarly with the other pairs of "facing" sides. It may be worth using these quick tests first, before diving into the complicated details of how exactly two colliding rectangles are in contact.

Because there are a lot of ways a pair of rectangles can be colliding! By my count, there are 16 different ways. There four kinds of "corner" collisions where exactly one corner of each rectangle is inside the other rectangle. Then you have eight "edge" collisions, where one edge of one rectangle is completely inside the other rectangle (one case for each edge of each rectangle). Then there are four cases where the rectangles have fully interpenetrated, either forming a cross shape (with two orientations) or where one rectangle is completely inside the other.

Now, for your game you may be able to rule out some of these kinds of collisions. If your objects move slowly relative to their size, so that no object's speed (in pixels/frame) exceeds any other object's size in a given dimension, you can skip the four interpenetration cases. And if all the objects are the same size, you can treat the edge cases like corner cases (or visa versa, maybe, with some tweaks). You might also be able to use your knowledge of the object's relative speeds to assess how they are colliding without diving into the exact details (e.g. if the player is moving to the right, his left side can't collide with a wall).

But all that depends on the details of your game. In a general purpose engine, you might need to solve for all 16 of the cases.

Comment: So I got the collision detection's to be handled for a large group of objects, however, now I have a different problem: The collisions are being detected, but not continuously. So, the player will halt on a solid object for a certain amount of time and then teleport through the object. This is consistent when approaching the object from the left/right sides. When the player approaches an object from the top/bottom, the player "slides" off, as in, it'll hit the top of the object, and then move over to the left/right side, and then hit the bottom and fall down (gravity applied).